# Why PHP built-in standard functions have empty body?

Tags: php, c++, c, backend, cgi

### How is this possible to have an empty body for a function ?

Is this related to **C/C++** (*that PHP is written with* ) ?
Or is it related to **CGI** mechanism or something like that ?

- I want to know how functions work under the hood.
- What if I want to add a simple function that returns "Hello world" written in C++ to PHP ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You're looking at documentation, not at function implementation.

Comment: You're probably better off googling for a tutorial on how to integrate `C++` with `PHP`. It is unlikely anyone will write such a tutorial for you here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are just dummy files (implemented by the IDE) that serve documentation & autocomplete purposes for the builtin functions / classes.

If you want to see how PHP works under the hood, take a look at its source code: https://github.com/php/php-src.

If you want to extend PHP with custom functions, you can write an extension in C++. There are a lot of tutorials on how to get started.